# how to enable access to files on the linux server via URL with password protection

Tags: linux, centos, url, authorization

I have a Linux centos 7 server. On that server, I started one script which should save images into one folder /images and inside the CSV file.

Is there any chance that I can make CSV file and folder images accessible through the URL with a password, so the users who have passwords can open the link and see the file and images?

Comment: What webserver are you using? apache?

Comment: not sure, how i can check it?

Comment: You should know if you installed one I suppose. [install apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) and [setup basic authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html)

Comment: i didnt install it, is that solution to my issue?

Comment: You want to serve files via a URL, for that you'll obviously need a webserver. If you setup authentication as described in the docs, that would be the solution to your issue.

Comment: this works!!! thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webserver to serve the files.

[Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) would be my first choice.

As the installation varies from distro to distro, I won't go any further into that here. Instructions for CentOS 7 can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7)

To make a URL/directory password protected, you can use basic HTTP authentication via a `.htaccess` file as described [here.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html)